# From where this table is created: "scconnector_google_feed_cl"

Tags: magento2, magento2.3.5

I have Magento 2.3.5. I have checked all code but I'm not able to find out from where this table `scconnector_google_feed_cl` is created in Magento2 database and what is the relation of this table with products table.

Can anyone know about this, please let me know.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is Magento_GoogleShoppingAds who creates this changelog table.

Answer (score 1):

Here is detail on how the changelog tables are created - https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/extension-dev-guide/indexing.html#m2devgde-mview

To see the relation, you should see theMySQL triggers by running `SHOW TRIGGERS;`

The cl table is created here:
`vendor/magento/framework/Mview/View/Changelog.php:create()`

and here the trigger is created:
`vendor/magento/framework/Mview/View/Subscription.php:create()`

Also, please note that the table is created when you set the reindex mode as update on schedule. If you change back to update on save this table will be dropped. Again if you set update on save it will be created.

Comment: From where this table is created `scconnector_google_feed_cl `. I mean from which module?

Comment: I have updated my reply. Accept as answer if it answers your question or let me know if you still have some more doubts